# Splitting a csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I've used the following code in numerous programs and it has always worked...until now.

```
a = open('Filename.csv', 'r')
ba = a.read()
a.close()
b = list(zip(*(e.split(',') for e in ba)))
```

It has always split the csv file on the commas.  Now I'm trying the same code with a csv file and it is splitting the file on each and every letter of the file, irregardless of letters or number, capital or small case letters.

Is there better code to use to split up a file on the commas?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I think I just found my stupid mistake, copying code from a couple of different sources doesn't always work the best, it should have been readlines(), not read()...once I saw it, just doing more head pounding, it finally caught my eye.